# How to send HTTP Commands through Port 80

Tags: sockets, http, tcp, port

Breif Description of what I am trying to accomplish. So I am working with Crestrons Simpl+ software. My job is to create a module for a sound masking system called QT Pro. Now, QT Pro has an API where you can control it via HTTP. I need a way to establish a connection with the QT Pro via HTTP( I have everything I need, IP, Username, Password).

Whats the problem? I have just started working with this language. Unfortunately there isn't as much documentation as I would like, otherwise I wouldn't be here. I know I need to create a socket connection via TCP on port 80. I just don't know what I'm supposed to send through it.

Here is an example:
http://username:password@address/cmd.htm?cmd=setOneZoneData&ZN=Value&mD=Value
&mN=Value&auxA=Value&auxB=Value&autoR=Value

If I were to put this into the URL box, and fill it in correctly. then it would change the values that I specify. Am I supposed to send the entire thing? Or just after cmd.htm? Or is there some other way I'm supposed to send data? I'd like to stay away from the TCP/IP Module so I can keep this all within the same module.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You send

```
GET /cmd.htm?cmd=setOneZoneData&ZN=Value&mD=Value&mN=Value&auxA=Value&auxB=Value&autoR=Value HTTP/1.1
Host: address
Connection: close
```

(End with a couple of newlines.)

If you need to use HTTP basic authentication, then also include a header like

```
Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

where the gibberish is the base64-encoded version of username:password.

But surely there is some mechanism for opening HTTP connections already there for you?  Just blindly throwing out headers like this and hoping the response is what you expect is not robust, to say the least.

To see what is going on with your requests and responses, a great tool is netcat (or telnet, for that matter.)

Do `nc address 80` to connect to server `address` on port 80, then paste your HTTP request:

```
GET /cmd.htm HTTP/1.1
Host: address
Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
Connection: close
```

and see what comes back. SOMETHING should come back. (Remember to terminate with two newlines.)

To see what requests your browser is sending when you do something that works, you can listen like this: `nc -l -p 8080`.
Then direct your browser to localhost:8080 with the rest of the URL as before, and you'll see the request that was sent. (Then you can type back to see how the browser handles the response.)

Comment: There are functions for opening a socket connection, the rest is up to me. I wish there was an easier way. The only problem right now is the fact that I have to use WWW-Authentication. I tried using the header for it. But no response from the QTPro. This is what I have
GET /zonedata_1.htm HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.10.70
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46c2VjcmV0
Connection: close

Comment: @DanielB: Try using netcat (or telnet) to debug—I added some info to my answer.

Comment: I have been using wireshark to watch the traffic so see if anything is coming back. But I'm not even getting a single thing from the QT Pro. I was able to get a response one time. But have been unsuccessful in recreating this effect. Thank you for your help by the way.

Comment: Make sure you are ending with at least two newlines, otherwise your request isn't complete and nothing will come back. But with that, just about any server should at least return an error. It's possible the QT Pro has a very restricted HTTP implementation that only responds to specific formats. Listen in as you do it with the browser—if you send exactly the same request the browser does, you should get the same response.

Comment: How would I end with two new lines do i just insert \n?

Comment: @DanielB: Sure, I mean, the same way you put in the newlines after each of the headers, I suppose. I don't know anything about the platform you are programming in.

Comment: You were right, that was the issue all along. Thanks!